# How to create a composer package for Symfony

Tags: package, composer-php, symfony4

I'm using Symfony 4 and want to create a composer package.

I want to put my Symfony project files on GitHub and create a composer package from the repository.

Does anyone have any advise on how to go about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can provide composer packages by creating and submitting them to packagist

You create a composer.json file and upload that to your github account and link that with your packagist account.

[Here is a guide on how to do this](https://packagist.org/about)

And then you would just need to create instructions on how to integrate it with Symfony.